# Mysql Connection lost

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I've one project with codeigniter. I made a query based on 4 table . it w=was working properly, but now total entry 50000+ .  Now when I do query it lost mysql connection. I increase time out and buffer size. but not work. Here is the qyery:

```
select temp.id office_id , temp.office_name, temp.svcic,
  count(service_transaction.service_id) as service_total 
from 
  (select users.id, users.office_name ,service_list.id svcic 
   from users,service_list WHERE users.del_status = 0 
   and users.type='agency' 
   and service_list.del_status = 0 
   and users.id != '-1' ) temp 
LEFT JOIN service on temp.id = service.office_id 
  and service.del_status = 0 
  AND (service.date BETWEEN '2017-08-09' AND '2017-09-09') 
LEFT JOIN service_transaction on service_transaction.service_id = temp.svcic 
  and service_transaction.service_transaction_id = service.id 
LEFT JOIN recipient on recipient.id = service.recipient_number 
  and recipient.gender != 'all' 
group by temp.id , temp.office_name, temp.svcic 
ORDER BY temp.office_name
```

[image]

Now what can I do ?

Comment: see this it might help you http://www.techrepublic.com/article/three-easy-ways-to-optimize-your-mysql-queries/

Comment: Use "EXPLAIN" to get the query plan for the query (Just add "EXPLAIN" before the query and run it).
I'm guessing that the full join in the inner query gives you too many rows, but if you paste the output of "EXPLAIN" here it would be easy to see.

Comment: 50000+ entries is not a lot. It's not CodeIgniter giving you problems, it's something else, probably server related.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't communicate much. Instead use the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` which includes information on indexes. Also: Email addreses are *frequently* longer than 50 characters. Use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default "string" field, don't limit it unless you have very specific requirements.

Comment: Likewise, `INT(50)` is nonsense because an int cannot hold numbers that big. Just use the default which is typically `INT(11)`.